# Generator loss keeps increasing while discriminator keeps decreasing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, gan, generative-models

I am trying to build a GAN to generate LEGO images however my generator is not working at all. I have tried changing the learning rates but it caused the loss to go even more higher, sometimes into thousands as well.

```
class GAN(Model):
    def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim):
        super(GAN, self).__init__()
        self.discriminator = make_discriminator()
        self.generator = make_generator()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super(GAN, self).compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn
        self.d_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="d_loss")
        self.g_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="g_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.d_loss_metric, self.g_loss_metric]

    def train_step(self, real_images):
        # Sample random points in the latent space
        batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Decode them to fake images
        generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors)

        # Combine them with real images
        combined_images = tf.concat([generated_images, real_images], axis=0)

        # Assemble labels discriminating real from fake images
        labels = tf.concat(
            [tf.ones((batch_size, 1)), tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0
        )
        # Add random noise to the labels - important trick!
        labels += 0.05 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels))

        # Train the discriminator
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(combined_images)
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        )

        # Sample random points in the latent space
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Assemble labels that say "all real images"
        misleading_labels = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        # Train the generator (note that we should *not* update the weights
        # of the discriminator)!
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(self.generator(random_latent_vectors))
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))

        # Update metrics
        self.d_loss_metric.update_state(d_loss)
        self.g_loss_metric.update_state(g_loss)
        return {
            "d_loss": self.d_loss_metric.result(),
            "g_loss": self.g_loss_metric.result(),
        }

class GAN(Model):
    def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim):
        super(GAN, self).__init__()
        self.discriminator = make_discriminator()
        self.generator = make_generator()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super(GAN, self).compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn
        self.d_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="d_loss")
        self.g_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="g_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.d_loss_metric, self.g_loss_metric]

    def train_step(self, real_images):
        # Sample random points in the latent space
        batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Decode them to fake images
        generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors)

        # Combine them with real images
        combined_images = tf.concat([generated_images, real_images], axis=0)

        # Assemble labels discriminating real from fake images
        labels = tf.concat(
            [tf.ones((batch_size, 1)), tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0
        )
        # Add random noise to the labels - important trick!
        labels += 0.05 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels))

        # Train the discriminator
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(combined_images)
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        )

        # Sample random points in the latent space
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Assemble labels that say "all real images"
        misleading_labels = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        # Train the generator (note that we should *not* update the weights
        # of the discriminator)!
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(self.generator(random_latent_vectors))
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))

        # Update metrics
        self.d_loss_metric.update_state(d_loss)
        self.g_loss_metric.update_state(g_loss)
        return {
            "d_loss": self.d_loss_metric.result(),
            "g_loss": self.g_loss_metric.result(),
        }
```

Kindly help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.